# basic typeahead.js not working?

Tags: jquery, typeahead.js

i have been asking this after all the research and editing the code for hours,i want to implement the typehead.js to implement autocomplete but its not working i will be very thankfull if anyone can help me with this...

```
<div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
                <div id="the-basics">
    <input class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="States of USA">
                </div>
                <script>

  $(document).ready(function () {
var substringMatcher = function(strs) {
  return function findMatches(q, cb) {
    var matches, substringRegex;

    // an array that will be populated with substring matches
    matches = [];

    // regex used to determine if a string contains the substring `q`
    substrRegex = new RegExp(q, 'i');

    // iterate through the pool of strings and for any string that
    // contains the substring `q`, add it to the `matches` array
    $.each(strs, function(i, str) {
      if (substrRegex.test(str)) {
        matches.push(str);
      }
    });

    cb(matches);
  };
};

var states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California',
  'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii',
  'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana',
  'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota',
  'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire',
  'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Carolina', 'North Dakota',
  'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island',
  'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont',
  'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming'
];

$('#the-basics .typeahead').typeahead({
  hint: true,
  highlight: true,
  minLength: 1
},
{
  name: 'states',
  source: substringMatcher(states)
});
}
</script>

                <!--<span class="input-group-addon info"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></span></span>-->
            </div></div>
```

Comment: What are the errors you are getting?

Comment: there are no errors....only it is no suggesting the values

Comment: Check console. There must be errors.

Comment: can you tell me how to check that  there were no errors displayed on screen

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list before </script>

Comment: help me with this,i have been trying for hours ...

Comment: You have a missing `);` at the end of your script.

Comment: I just set up a fiddle for you to compare. Check it out. --> http://jsfiddle.net/hgLy3uzf/

Comment: i have already corrected that mistake but still it doesnt work....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83372/discussion-between-patel-and-optimmus).

Comment: does css can also create problem in this case

Comment: @Optimmus can you create a jsfiddle please? I was facing the similar issue and managed to resolve. I might be help here if I see the code along with js libraries (versions) that you are using.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ershadow_786/51kL3k09/

Comment: Your jsfiddle is broken coz of - `Mixed Content: The page at 'https://fiddle.jshell.net/ershadow_786/51kL3k09/show/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/releases/latest/typeahead.bundle.min.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`  I have created this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/xBB5x/8930/   slightly different implementation. I am using Bloodhound suggestion engine. Hope it helps. I will post this as answer with more details if you think this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem may be that if you are using Bootstrap 3.x.x in which typeahead was removed.

You can use Twitter typeahead.js library. There is a nice blog post about it (in the end also about simple integration): [https://blog.twitter.com/2013/twitter-typeaheadjs-you-autocomplete-me](https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead)

Update

There is also projexct on github which provides back typeahead in Bootstrap: https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead

Comment: This reduces errors in console but still autocomplete does not work